# MathJax will not render in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, mathjax

I am trying to get MathJax to render inside of an iframe. [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asc1zuc3/) with a simple example. You can see the "MathJax loading" banner at the bottom when you run the fiddle, but the text in the iframe is not rendered. (Should render like the attached image).

[image: expected output]

My code is reproduced here:

html:

```
<iframe id="my-frame" srcdoc="<div>This is \(\mu_s\). </div>">
```

javascript:

```
var mathJax = 'https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full',
            script = document.createElement('script'),
            initScript = document.createElement('script');

        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = mathJax;

        initScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        initScript.text = '$(document).on("ready", function () {MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);});';

$('#my-frame').contents().find('head').append(script);
$('#my-frame').contents().find('body').append(initScript);
```

I have looked at the [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802440/mathjax-not-working-with-iframe), but my case seems different (since I am calling MathJax Typeset from within the iframe). Similarly, [this old Google thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/9hBygNAD2To) indicates I need to load the MathJax script inside the iframe, which I am doing already. The [MathJax docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html) indicate that I should call `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);` when trying to queue up rendering of dynamic content, which I am doing (though I suspect I may not need to manually queue up Typesetting?). MathJax is loaded in the `<head>` script of each iframe, [as recommended](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/dynamic.html).

Not quite sure what else to try, any help would be appreciated. The error I see in the console is `Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined`, which makes me think that it is not loading properly inside of the iframe...

Thanks!

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.  First, you don't need the `initScript`, since MathJax will run once automatically (and even if you did, since jQuery isn't loaded in the iframe, you couldn't do `$(document).on()` anyway).  Also, you should be creating the script element in the iframe's document, not the outer document (they aren't the same).

You are on the right track otherwise, but it turns out that jQuery is messing you up somehow.  The `append()` call does something funny and MathJax ends up running in the outer window, not the inner one.  I'm not sure quite how that is happening, but the solution is to use the regular `appendChild()` method rather than jQuery for this.  So if you use

```
var doc = $('#my-frame').contents()[0];

var script = doc.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full';

// $('#my-frame').contents().find('head').append(script);  // this is the line that is causing trouble.
doc.head.appendChild(script);
```

it should work for you (it did for me).

Comment: thanks. My use case got a little more complicated, but this does indeed work better (I realized about injecting jQuery into the iframe too, but that didn't help).

Answer (score 0):

I wound up doing this by editing the source doc itself, instead of trying to inject MathJax after the fact...[working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/asc1zuc3/1/)

```
<iframe id="my-frame" srcdoc="<html><head><script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full'></script></head><body><div>This is \(\mu_s\). </div></body></html>">
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.